# Как наложить маску яндекс карты регионы

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как наложить маску в яндекс картах регионы?

Пример с http://dimik.github.io/ymaps/examples/regions/ я знаю. Во всем рунете только на него и ссылаются. Конкретно на два файла - mask-overlay.js и region-selector-map-mask-view.js, но они не работают у меня.

API подключено 2,1 а в примере этом 2,0. Может из-за этого? Или в этих файлах нужно что-то подправить? Есть те, кто уже сталкивался с этим вопросом и сумел его реализовать?

Comment: Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: маска не отображается на картах. спотыкается на строчке:  ymaps.util.augment(MaskOverlay, ymaps.overlay.staticGraphics.Polygon - кидает ошибку Cannot read property 'Polygon' of undefined

Comment: Видимо нет такого слоя на карте. В чем именно состоит ваша задача? Приведите код, над которым вы работаете (лучше часть кода, которая воспроизводит проблему)

Comment: собрал код который выделяет карту России и некоторые области на ней. Это работает. Нужно спрятать все остальное за пределами выделенной области, для этого добавил к себе код из этих двух js файлов, но ничего не произошло. из ошибки пока только вышеприведенная.

Comment: API 2.1 и 2.0 обратно несовместимы. Поэтому, код, написанный для 2.0 может не работать с API 2.1. Есть инструкции по переходу с версии на версию: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/update/concepts/update-docpage/